# How to simulate a swipe gesture on a Card in a Composable Test?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso, android-testing, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I have an app that has a composable `MyCard()`.

I am testing the app in `myTest()` and would like to simulate a `swipeRight` gesture on the card.

When I use `performTouchInput { swipeRight() }` nothing happens. The UI does not update and card stays in the same place.

How can I simulate swipe right gesture on the card? What am I missing?

### Desired Result

[image]

### Code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class MyTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeRule = createComposeRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        composeRule.setContent {
             MyCard()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun myTest() = runTest {
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag("DraggableCard")
            .performTouchInput { swipeRight() }
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedTransitionTargetStateParameter")
@Composable
fun MyCard() {
    var swipeState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val transitionState = remember {
        MutableTransitionState(swipeState).apply { targetState = !swipeState }
    }
    val transition = updateTransition(transitionState, "cardTransition")

    val offsetTransition by transition.animateFloat(
        label = "cardOffsetTransition",
        transitionSpec = { tween(durationMillis = 300) },
        targetValueByState = { if (swipeState) 75f else 0f },)

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .testTag("DraggableCard")
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(35.dp)
            .padding(horizontal = 4.dp, vertical = 1.dp)
            .offset { IntOffset(offsetTransition.roundToInt(), 0) }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectHorizontalDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                    when {
                        dragAmount >= 6 -> { swipeState = true }
                        dragAmount < -6 -> { swipeState = false }
                    }
                }
            },
        backgroundColor = Color.Gray,
        content = { Text(text = "Hello") }
    )
}
```

Comment: i also want to know this, did you find a solution?

Comment: @dqualias see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to be careful with which node I was swiping right on and how I controlled the tests `autoclock`.

If it is not working, try swiping right different nodes in the semantics hierarchy, not the card itself.

Below is the pseudo code that eventually worked for me.

```kotlin
private fun swipeRight(symbol: String) {
    composeRule.waitForIdle()

    composeRule.mainClock.autoAdvance = false

    composeRule.onNode(hasText("DraggableCard"))
        .performTouchInput { swipeRight() }

    composeRule.mainClock.advanceTimeBy(ANIMATION_DURATION.toLong() + 5L) /*add 5s buffer*/

    composeRule.mainClock.autoAdvance = true

    composeRule.onNode(hasText("DraggableCard")).assertExists()
        .performClick()

}
```

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("UnusedTransitionTargetStateParameter")
@Composable
fun DraggableCard(
    isSwiped: Boolean,
    cardHeight: Dp,
    cardOffset: Float,
) {
    val transitionState = remember {
        MutableTransitionState(isSwiped).apply {
            targetState = !isSwiped
        }
    }
    val transition = updateTransition(transitionState, "cardTransition")

    val offsetTransition by transition.animateFloat(
        label = "cardOffsetTransition",
        transitionSpec = { tween(durationMillis = 300) },
        targetValueByState = { if (isSwiped) cardOffset else 0f },
        )

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .semantics(mergeDescendants = false) {
                testTag = "DraggableCard"
            }
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(cardHeight)
            .offset { IntOffset(offsetTransition.roundToInt(), 0) }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectHorizontalDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                    when {
                        dragAmount >= 6 -> {}
                        dragAmount < -6 -> {}
                    }
                }
            },
        content =
        { Text(text = "Hello") }
    )
}
```